How to color your hair formed by particle system and then converted to mesh?
I created a model and gave hair particle system to it and later convert it to mesh using particle system modifier -> convert to mesh. Now I want to give a material to this hair mesh and I assign a new material to this mesh but It will not show that material on the mesh. What is the problem with this?

Should not it work like a normal mesh when we add color to it via materials?

What if you go in Edit mode, select all the mesh and hit the assign button in the properties editor > material tab ?

You cannot assign a material to the converted hair particles because such a mesh has no faces. It consists only of edges. Such a mesh cannot be rendered nor assigned a material. You need faces. If you want to use the model in a game engine I recommend checking out so-called hair cards. These are transparent planes that have hair drawn on them. Otherwise, you can convert the hair mesh to curves, bevel them to create faces and convert the curves to a mesh again. But beware that this creates a lot of extra geometry. Maybe extruding the edges to tiny planes with Geometry Nodes could work, too.

Here is an example of how to create planes from the hair curves. In your case, you need to convert the (old) hair particles to the (new) hair curves first. Note that you will get a lot of planes, one for each hair.

@Lauloque No, I tried it but it does not get any color. I guess Blunder is right I still have to try what the said. But thanks so the help man.

@Blunder Actually I want to export this model to a glb file and import it in three.js environment, I will not be rendering it.
I tried the first method you told but the hair wont bevel after i convert them to curve.
I will try you second method hope it works!

Here's an example of method 1. Convert the particles to a mesh as you did. Then use menu (1) Object > Convert > Curve to convert it to the old curves. (The new hair curves is Curves with an s in the name.). The icon (2) changes in the outliner. Now you can use the (3) Bevel settings in the Object Data Properties tab to create thin cylinders. The option works in a similar way to a modifier & creates a mesh from the curve object. The object is still a curve but the output geometry is mesh.For export you need to convert it 1 last time.

[...] To create a real mesh object finally, use the menu entry (1) Object > Convert > Mesh. In the example, Suzanne had 5000 hair particles. As you can see in the status bar (4) the converted mesh has now 220,500 faces. The number depends on the Resolution value in the Bevel settings. -- The advantage of hair cards is that they don't generate so much geometry, as the hair is only painted on using an image texture. It's kinda fake hair. More info about that: https://80.lv/articles/making-hair-and-beards-for-aaa-games/ and https://www.youtube.com/live/oqjKMd9CYI4

That really should be posted as an answer...

@Blunder This is it! thanks man. Post it as an answer I got it thanks buddy.
